# Наложение нескольких изображений в canvas без отображения во время процесса

Tags: javascript, изображения, canvas, обработка-изображений

Я обрабатываю сразу несколько изображений последовательно, передавая их в canvas.

Во время обработки (наложения) они отображаются на странице. Мне это не нужно. Мне нужно отображать лишь результат (в данный момент лишь одну из всех обрабатываемых, но могут понадобиться и все).

Возможно вы сможете подсказать, как делать такие операции с canvas без отображения картинки во время непосредственно обработки.

EDIT:
Изначально искал библиотеку для JS, которая является аналогом pillow в python. Но с необходимыми функциями справлялся canvas, за исключением преждевременного отображения. В коментариях помогли решить этот вопрос.

Comment: не ясен вопрос: тебе нужна какая-то библиотека или просто скрыть один из canvas'ов?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Вроде как можно просто создать канвас в js `let x = document.createElement("CANVAS");` и просто работать с ним не вставляя сам канвас на страницу.

Comment: @DmitryLazenyuk да, помогло. Не знаю как я сразу не подумал об этом. Спасибо!